# How can I stop do-while in windows form app by clicking on a button?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use a button in windows form app to stop do-while. When I click on stop button, the stop button does not work. How can I do it?

```
do{     
            …….    
  } while (stop == 0);


In Stop button:
stop = 1;
```

Comment: Very little code to guess the issue or cause. Can you charge bit more code around what starts the loop, how you try to stop the loop, where stop variable is declared etc?

Comment: Are you sure the variable `stop` is the same in both methods. Also check if clicking the button hits the handler and makes `stop` equals to 1.

Comment: Unless the `do…while` loop starts under a different thread, than the main UI thread… then the UI will become “locked” until the do/while loop exits. While the loop is running the user will NOT be able to “click” the stop button. It may help to describe why you want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your loop in a `Task` or `async void`, and use a `CancellationToken` to stop it

**Given**

```
private static CancellationTokenSource _cs;
private static CancellationToken _token;


public static async Task StartWhile()
{
   while (!_token.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("looping");
      await Task.Delay(1000);
   }

   Console.WriteLine("loop stopped");

}
```

**Usage**

```
   _cs = new CancellationTokenSource();
   _token = _cs.Token;

   Task.Run(StartWhile);

   Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");

   var result = Console.ReadKey();

   Console.WriteLine("You Pressed "+ result.Key);
   _cs.Cancel();

   Console.WriteLine("loop stopped");

   Console.ReadKey();
```

**Output**

```
Press any key to exit
looping
looping
looping
looping
You Pressed Enter
loop stopped
```

Or a Winforms example

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      btnStart.Enabled = false;

      _cs = new CancellationTokenSource();
      _token = _cs.Token;

      while (!_token.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
         Debug.WriteLine("looping");
         await Task.Delay(1000);
      }

      Debug.WriteLine("loop stopped");
   }
   finally
   {
      btnStart.Enabled = true;
   }
}

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("You Cancelled");
   _cs?.Cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@JohnG's comment above basically sums up the issue you are probably having. You can't do a long-running set of computations on the User-Interface (UI) thread. You have to shuffle that off to another thread or task.

This is where *parallel* programming comes in: You want to click a button, have that initiate some work, but also allow for the UI to allow the user to click another button to stop that work.

So, here is a small example of what we are talking about:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

private async void BtnStartWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BtnStartWork.Enabled = false;
    _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() => CPUBoundWork(_tokenSource.Token));
    }
    finally
    {
        _tokenSource.Dispose();
        _tokenSource = null;
        BtnStartWork.Enabled = true;
    }
        
}

private void BtnStopWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // signal cancel -- everyone listening will be notified.
    _tokenSource?.Cancel();
}

private void CPUBoundWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // signaled for cancel, leave immediatly.
            break;
        }
        // simulate CPU-bound work:
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Some things may look new to you, for example: The `BtnStartWork_Click` method has the keyword `async` in it's signature. There is the keyword `await` being used. I won't explain everything going on here because there are [plenty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) [of resources](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) [out there](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/understand-control-flow-async-await) about the subject.

But, this is the general idea of parallel programming. Your UI thread is still free to process messages dealing with the UI, and the framework makes sure to do the tasks you need it to do... all this with very little effort for the programmer.